# How to observe different concepts of an interface separately?

Tags: model-view-controller, generics, interface, f#

Basically, what I am trying to do is have a generic simulator-interface which acts as the lose coupling between the model and the user interface, which acts as the view. My simulator interface looks like this:

```
type ISimulator<'Collection, 'Item, 'Value> =
  inherit System.IObservable<'Collection>
  inherit System.IObservable<ISimulator<'Collection, 'Item, 'Value>>
  abstract Start:           unit -> unit
  abstract Stop:            unit -> unit
  abstract Reset:           unit -> unit
  abstract Reset:           'Collection -> unit
  abstract Advance:         int<gen> -> unit
  abstract InitialState:    'Collection
    with get
  abstract CurrentState:    'Collection
    with get
  abstract Rule:            ('Item -> 'Value)
    with get, set
  abstract Generation:      int<gen>
    with get, set
  abstract Speed:           float<gen/sec>
    with get, set
  abstract Running:         bool
    with get
```

'Collections is the type of a data collection, 'Item is the type of a single data item, and 'Value is the type of its actual value (for example <Matrix, Cell, float>, <Tree, Node, string> etc.). Now, the line

```
inherit System.IObservable<ISimulator<'Collection, 'Item, 'Value>>
```

produces an error:

```
This type implements or inherits the same interface at different generic instantiations 'System.IObservable<Interface.ISimulator<'Collection,'Item,'Value>>' and 'System.IObservable<'Collection>'. This is not permitted in this version of F#.
```

Effectively, I want this interface to say that both the Collection which serves as the data the simulation is running upon and the Simulator itself to be observable separately. In the end, I want a part of my user interface to display the current data (for example a matrix) and a different part to display and control the simulator, with some buttons like "run", "stop", "reset" etc. Since the simulator might also be stopped by other means than just clicking a button (for example, after reaching some specific state, generation etc.), that control needs updates from the simulator, too, but not on the state of the data, but the simulator itself.

It is not possible to make the collection interface I would write observable, as that collection wouldn't be modified during simulation, but transformed by applying a function, and the transformation would produce a new collection, which the simulator then stores (and notifies the observers of the collection).

What shall I do?

- Break the immutability concept and
  always keep the same collection (in
  terms of identity, not contained
  values) which just changes over time
  instead of producing new, modified
  collections?
- Break lose coupling and have my user
  interface know the exact
  implementation which would, outside
  of the interface, provide a second
  means to observer the simulator
  itself? Have all user interface
  components which require updates from
  the simulator observe the whole
  thing, not just the relevant data?
- Create a seperate interface to
  observe the collection, and have my
  simulator implementation implement
  both interfaces?
- Something else?

Comment: Why is the code being colored in such weird, unpredictable way? Except for the error mentioned, this code is valid F#, if I remove the offending line, it compiles perfectly.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not syntax highlight F# source code correct. Specifically, it is getting confused by the ' in `'a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered exposing the observables through properties, sort of like traditional events?

```
type ISimulator<'Collection, 'Item, 'Value> =
  abstract Items:           System.IObservable<'Collection>
  abstract Control:         System.IObservable<ISimulator<'Collection, 'Item, 'Value>>
  abstract Start:           unit -> unit
  ...
```

This allows consumers to be explicit about which behavior they're observing.

Comment: Ok, I have finally decided to go that route, i.e. composition, and provide bare-bones generic implementation of IObservable of which I expose proterties like you described. I am still not sure if it's the best solution, but better than anything else I could think of so far. ;)

Comment: If you do come up with something better, let us know. :)

Comment: Well, now that I have a ready-made implementation of IObservable, this isn't too bad actually. Basically, I have implemented the interface plus methods to activate the "OnNext", "OnError" and "OnCompleted" events on all registered observers, and just have instances of this class. As public properties. I will post the implementation in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, I made this bare-bones implementation of IObservable, of which I then expose public properties according to the interface definition dahlbyk provided. I've found the basic idea for this implementation on [this website](http://www.navision-blog.de/2009/10/22/iobservable-iobserver-using-the-reactive-framework-with-fsharp-part-ii/) and generalized a bit from there:

```
  open System

  type Observable<'a>() =
    let mutable _observers: List<IObserver<'a>> = []
    let Notify func =
      _observers
      |> Seq.map(fun (observer: IObserver<'a>) -> async { return func observer} )
      |> Async.Parallel
      |> Async.RunSynchronously
      |> ignore

    interface IObservable<'a> with

      member this.Subscribe (observer: IObserver<'a>) =
        _observers <- observer :: _observers
        { new IDisposable with
              member this.Dispose() =
                _observers <- _observers |> List.filter((<>) observer) }

    member this.Next value =
      Notify(fun (observer: IObserver<'a>) -> observer.OnNext value)

    member this.Error error =
      Notify(fun (observer: IObserver<'a>) -> observer.OnError error)

    member this.Completed() =
      Notify(fun (observer: IObserver<'a>) -> observer.OnCompleted)
```

The class containing instances of this implementation as properties just treats it as an `Observable<'a>` object, while to everyone else it is exposed only as an `IObservable<'a>` interface. I think this is nice in terms of loose coupling and still allows very straightforward usage on either end of the Observer/Observable pair.

P.S.: This is also why I love F# - this entire construct would be a total mess to implement in a language like C++; but here I can just pass a function into another function in order to apply it on all observers. :)